# How can I select items from a table that was edited the last time atleast one year ago?

Tags: sql

I'm currently stuck with a SQL query. I need to select items where the last time they were edited is at least one year old. It keeps happening that items are selected that were changed yesterday.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    l100.identnr, bu_dat, tabzwischen.letztesdatum
FROM 
    l100
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         l100.identnr, MAX(bu_dat) AS letztesdatum
     FROM 
         l100
     WHERE 
         YEAR(bu_dat) = 2020, YEAR TO SECOND)
     GROUP BY 1) AS tabzwischen ON l100.identnr = tabzwischen.identnr
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: And define "year ago" in this context. Is 1.3.2020 out of your "year ago" scope? Your query looks like you want to search items from last year (1.1.2020 - 31.12.2020) instead of more than year ago (today before 9.3.2020)

Comment: This cannot be your actual query - it has 3 `(` and 4 `)`... `YEAR(bu_dat) = 2020, YEAR TO SECOND)` seems to be a syntax error